# preg_replace every except: spaces, (, ), numbers, AND, OR

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace everything except the following:

```
spaces
(
)
numbers
AND
OR
```

Here's my current code which almost works except it allows any of the letters from *ANDOR* to be left.

I want it to only leave the full word AND or OR otherwise strip it.

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^()ANDOR0-9 ]/", "", $string);
```

Any ideas what code I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a1 = array("AND", "OR");
$a2 = array("&","|");
$result = str_replace($a2, $a1, preg_replace("/[^()0-9 &|]/", "", str_replace($a1, $a2, preg_replace("/[^()ANDOR0-9 ]/", "", $string))));
```

Not very elegant, but it works.